# MVC calling a script with a key

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a button that calls data to textboxes. But I want to do this with the enter key, not with a button.

This script calls the datas.

```
<script>
function AboneBul() {
    location.href = "/Home/AboneBul/" + document.getElementById('ABONE_NO').value + "";
}
```

And this piece of code is the buttons code.

```
                <div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AboneBul()" value="Abone Getir" />

                </div>
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

this example from w3school, it might help somehow.

```
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user releases a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

[the source link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp)